# Allow IIS_USR to connect to SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, iis-6

I have a problem to connect to a SQL Server database with a web application that use ADO.

I have one server under Windows Server 2008 with domain controller role and another server under Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0

Before, SQL Server was on the same server that IIS thus we did not have problems but now SQL Server is on another server.

How must I do ?

Thanks

Comment: is remote access enable on the sql server?

Comment: yes, we have another application (under VB6) and we don't have problems

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a domain user, let's say ABLA\dubli.doo on the win2k8, allow access to the servers for this dubli.doo user, and run the IIS6 thingy with this one instead of IIS_IUSRS?
The reason: IIS_IUSRS is a local user of the win2k3 server and I see not much chance of it working well with the other - win2k8 SQL. Okay, you have a built-in IIS_IUSRS account, but if you want custom, just customize.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a SQL account in your connection string?  How is your connection string setup? Could you post it here replacing the server name and username/password with dummy info?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows you to use userids stored in the SQL Server or userids from a Windows domain. Do you know which kind of userids your database is configured to use?

Comment: both application (web and rich) connect to SQL Database with a SQL server connection, not a windows user

Answer (score 0):

I found where is the problem, I tried to disconnect the windows firewall and it works fine. Anybody knows what is the port number that I have to open in this case ?

Edit : I found by showing firewall logs that UDP packets on remote port 1434 (SQL Browser) were dropped so I added a rule for this port number and it works